# Javascript, AngularJS - Global variable not being correctly assigned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global-variables, scope, single-page-application

The scope variable $scope.quizArray appears as undefined when accessed from the controller. The block of code below is definitely read as I have previously put tests in.

```
 app.factory('getQuizService', function($http){
     return {
          getQuiz:function(videoId,scope){

          var $promise=$http.post("http://localhost/PHP/getQuiz.php", {'videoId': videoId});
                $promise.then(function(msg){

                          scope.quizArray = "TEST";

                        });
           }
     }
    });
```

Controller code - The service is called by:

```
function getQuizList(){
       getQuizService.getQuiz(videoIdService.getId(),$scope);
       alert($scope.quizArray);
      }
```

however the alert produces the result 'undefined' instead of 'TEST'

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is using promises, but you are not, so by the time you alert it is not defined, quizArray is only set to TEST when the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're doing it like this?
Take a look at the approach(es) below:

Refer to: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q for more information about how the promises work.

For example, the reason why the approach that lib3d has pointed out works:

> then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.
>
> This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback. It also notifies via the return value of the notifyCallback method. The promise can not be resolved or rejected from the notifyCallback method.

**Code:**

```
app.factory('getQuizService', function($http){
 return {
      getQuiz:function(videoId,scope){

      return $http.post("http://localhost/PHP/getQuiz.php", {'videoId': videoId});

      //If you want to handle the promise here, you can include the $q service in your controller and do this:
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.post("...").then(function(data) {
        //Special treatment here
        deferred.resolve(data)
      }, function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error)
      })

      return deferred.promise

      //As indicated by lib3d, you can directly do this as well:
      return $http.post("...").then(function(data) {
            //treatment
            return data
      }, function(error) {
            //error handling      
      });

 }
}).controller("Ctrl", function($scope, getQuizService) {

  getQuizService.getQuiz(1).then(function(data) {
    $scope.quizArray = data;
    //Code when everything goes ok,
  }, function(error) {
    //Code when everything goes false;
  })
})
```

Comment: The second promise `deferred` is unnecessary. Don't resolve it with transformed data, return the transformed data. Don' reject it with the error, throw the error, or don't implement the error handler at all if no special behaviour.

Comment: And don't return the `deferred.promise`, return what returns the call to `then`. But that is just improvement hints :)

Comment: What's the point of a promise if you're only going to return the data when it's done? I've listed two returns as an example, the first lets the controller directly handle the $http return call, the second promise lets your service do additional manipulations. if you wouldn't use the deferred you'd have to wait on the $http.post to be complete before returning anything, which would block the process, no?

Comment: Your second return would look like the first (you still return outside the handlers) except that you would chain with a `then` call with the first arg being a function returning the transformed data and the second optional arg throwing the incoming error.

Comment: Aha, did not know that it worked like that as well. Clarified it in the answer.